# I am Getting the Object when i retrieve the values from the database in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am just a start up in spring mvc . My task is that i have list the values form the database into the dropdown list in the jsp page using the spring.
When i do so, am getting the object rather than the values.I use Controller,service,DAOand command class . Here is my code.

Service Class:

```
public class  EventService implements RowMapper<EventCommand> {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
     public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }
     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("eventManagementDAO")

     public IEventManagementDAO eventManagementDAO;

    @Override
    public EventCommand mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        EventCommand eventcommand=new EventCommand();   
        eventcommand.setemployee(rs.getString("firstname"));
        String test2=eventcommand.getemployee();        
        return eventcommand;

    } }
```

Here is the DAO class

```
public class EventManagementDAO implements IEventManagementDAO{
    public List<EventCommand> showEmployee(){
        EventList eventlist=new EventList();

    DataSource dataSource = DataFactory.getDataSource();
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    String sql = new String("SELECT empid,firstname from empde ") ;


    List<EventCommand> employee = (List<EventCommand>) template.query(sql, new EventService());  

    return employee;

}
}
```

Here is my JSP page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Assigning Employee for the Event</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form name="eventemployeeform" action="eventassign" commandName="eventCommand" method="POST">
<table><tr><td><h3>Select the event</h3></td><td><form:select path="Eventname">
<form:option value="0" label="Select" />
<form:options items="${eventname}" itemValue="eventname" itemLabel="eventname" />
</form:select><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Select the employee</h3></td><td>
<form:select path="Employee">
<form:option value="NONE" label="Select" />
<form:options items="${employeelist}"/>
</form:select></td></tr> 
<tr><td><h3>Select the Products</h3></td><td><form:select path="Products">
<form:option value="0" label="Select" />
<form:options items="${Products}" itemValue="products" itemLabel="products" />
</form:select><br/></td></tr>
</table>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller

```
public ModelAndView getemployeeassign(@ModelAttribute("eventCommand")EventCommand eventCommand){
        Map referenceData= new HashMap();
        List<EventCommand> newlist=new ArrayList<EventCommand>();


        newlist.addAll((service.eventManagementDAO.showEmployee()));
        referenceData.put("employeelist",newlist);
        return new ModelAndView("EventEmployee",referenceData);
    }
```

Here is my EventCommand class

```
package com.wity.command;

public class EventCommand {

    String Eventname;
    String employee;
    String Products;
    public String getEventname() {
        return Eventname;
    }
    public void setEventname(String Eventname) {
        this.Eventname = Eventname;
    }
    public String getemployee() {

        return employee;

    }
    public void setemployee(String employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
        //System.out.println(employee);

    }
    public String getProducts() {
        return Products;
    }
    public void setProducts(String Products) {
        this.Products = Products;
    }

}
```

****the program above reads the data from the database correctly(Multiple rows) but it displaying the object and not the string.****

Am getting the output as in the dropdown box as
Since i cannot post the images
my output is 
com.hari.command.EventCommand@131e2c6
com.hari.command.EventCommand@53a8a1
Help me to resolve it. I must get the values in the string rather then object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am getting it correctly, you have to specify proper value and label to display the proper value and post the proper id back once again to backend from JSP. For example, with `<form:select>` you can do like this...

```
<form:select path="employee" id="employeeSelect">
    <form:options items = "${employee}" itemValue="${employee.id}" itemLabel="${employee.firstname}"/>
</form:select>
```

For now I believe you are not specifying the property and that is why it is printing the object id, as the default toString().

Comment: I have tried your method bro, but the jsp error occurs. It shows the itemValue must not be employee.

Comment: Please change according to your list name. Initially I have given you a sample as the JSP code was not available. Try using itemValue="id" and itemLabel="firstName"(Or based on your property name).

Comment: tried bro...But it says, itemValue must not be empty.But when i put itemValue=${employee.firstname} it says 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "firstname"

Comment: Ok, please provide some other details. Please edit with your EventCommand class structure and the data (sample)  from the empde table. One more point I noticed, in the mapRow() method you are not setting the id to the object from result set. Please answer to investigate further.

Comment: bro... i have added the event command class. the program reads the data correctly from the database but it displays all the fields with the object name.

Comment: @Hariharan, as I mentioned earlier, the mapRow() method is not setting the 'empid' field in the object. There is no property also in the EventCommand object to hold your empid. Even I don't understand what you want to display in the dropdown as label to user and what you want to keep as value to be submitted? Please decide, assign the value which you want use as value and use it on JSP. As there was no value, that is why it complained "itemValue" must not be empty. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Bro... I want to display the firstname in the dropdown list . The firstname must be fetched from the database. You have said the empid should be set . can i know how to do it.??

Comment: @Hariharan, here are the steps...  1. Add a new property 'empid' to your EventCommand object and generate getters and setters.  2. In your mapRow() method, add 'eventcommand.setEmpid(rs.getString("empid"));'(Based on your setter method, database column name and type obviously). 3. As suggested earlier, use itemValue="empid" itemLabel="employee". I will definitely suggest to adhere to java bean standards as I can see 'setemployee' which should be 'setEmployee' and 'getEmployee'. If you are using an IDE, generate it through that.

Comment: Bro...awesome. It just worked... I have changed 

<form:options items="${employeelist}" itemValue="empid" itemLabel="employee"/> 

can you say what is meant by itemLabel="employee"    bro..???

Comment: This is the label what you want to show in the UI. Do a view source and you can see these as values and your empid as options.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I understood you 100%, but seems to me that on your JSP page you need to display `eventCommand.getEmployee()` instead of `eventCommand`. Hard to tell without your JSP page code.

Example:

```
<form:select path="Employee">
    <form:option value="NONE" label="Select" />
    <form:options items="${employeelist}" itemLabel="employee"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Friend , i have added the jso page for your reference.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Bro , I have done it so ,I displays the object only and not the String.

Comment: Try with `itemLabel="employee" itemValue="employee"`. If it doesn't work, try changing `EventCommand#getemployee()` to `EventCommand#getEmployee()` (with a capital E), I'm not sure how Spring handles all lowercase getters.

Comment: It says when i run the jsp page.

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '[com.wity.command.EventCommand@26ae1f, com.wity.command.EventCommand@1886758]' of bean class [com.wity.command.EventCommand]: Bean property '[com.wity.command.EventCommand@26ae1f, com.wity.command.EventCommand@1886758]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: You need to fix all the names in `EventCommand` class before going any further, because frameworks such as Spring rely on certain common naming conventions. For example `String Eventname` should be `String eventname` with getter and setter `getEventname(), setEventname()`. Also `String employee` should be coupled with `getEmployee()` and `setEmployee()`. Pay attention to case!